# Frontespizio not reloading

Tags: thesis, overleaf, frontespizio

```
\begin{frontespizio}
\Logo[3.5cm]{./pictures/Logo.pdf}
...
\end{frontespizio}
\IfFileExists{\jobname-frn.tex}{}{%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex \jobname-frn.tex}}
```

I am writing my thesis on Overleaf, and I want the frontpage to use the frontespizio package. It compiled ok the first time, but then I have tried to modify the title of my thesis and the output does not update.

```
\IfFileExists{\jobname-frn}{}{%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex \jobname-frn}}
```

Should not this part of the code force overleaf to compile the *-frn.tex file?

Comment: That code does nothing: as soon as `\end{frontespizio}` is scanned, the `\jobname-frn.tex` file is written out, so it exists. Just open the file and compile it as if it were a standard TeX file. You need to do it only if the frontispiece changes.

Comment: Thank you for answering me ... The point is that I am working on Overleaf; that means the \jobname-frn.tex file is not visible to me (or maybe yes but I don't know how...) so I cannot compile it. Nonetheless, I found that if I clear the cache then the frontispiece will be recompiled. I am still looking for some code that compile automatically the new frontispiece only if it is modified.